# upload image to cloudinary and save only the url in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, url, cloudinary

I want to create a photo gallery in Rails displaying the photos from Cloudinary. How to save the urls in the database to display them, or is there any other option to do it without saving the urls?

Many Thanks,

Imre

Answer (score 1):

Cloudinary has a pretty good documentation on how to integrate its service into a Rails app. Start by adding the gem to your gem file.

http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration

What you describe: "...save only url to the Database' is basically the principle of their service.  You save the image itself in their cloud and the gem provides you a @model.name_url helper inside your app as well as a url for the image. 
They offer different options of setting up their cloud service with Ruby and Rails, and much can be found in their docs.

Cloudinary also has a good Doc on how to integrate carrierwave and cloudinary together for image upload.
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_carrierwave

Comment: In case you integrate carrierwave and cloudinary together and you upload images to your gallery, you can later call in views for example: =image_tag(@photo_gallery.avatar_url(:standard)) etc...

Comment: You might also find the sample project pretty helpful - https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/tree/master/samples/photo_album

Comment: Thanks for the link, I don't want the user to create a gallery, only I want to use the cloud images and to store of their urls and then display it on the view. Basically, I only want to import the urls in my database from the cloud

Comment: Well, you can create a URL field for your photos and store the URL or your can name your images during upload so that the name matches a pattern. Both are possible. If you want to store the url you need to get it from after upload and than store to your DB. They also have options to give filenames etc. Hope that helps.